# Как правильно организовать выборку и генерацию древовидной структуры из нескольких таблиц MySQL с разными полями?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 3 таблицы со своими (разными) полями:

```
country | city | street
```

Вопрос:
Как создать древовидную структуру вложенностей из этих 3 таблиц(например json массив) такого типа:

```
{
  "country1": {
     "name_country": <name>
     ... другие поля из таблицы country
     "city_array": {
           "city1": {
                "name": <name>,
                ... другие поля из таблицы city           
                "street_array": {
                        "street1": {
                            "namestreet": <name>
                            ... другие поля из таблицу street
                                   }
                                }
```

На всякий случай публикую как я сделал сейчас:

```
$country = DB::query('SELECT * FROM `country`');

// массив стран с ключом по id
$country_id = Transform::groupMassBykey($country,'id');

// массив из ключей id стран (что бы вытащить города)
$country_id_array = array_column($country, 'id');

//города
$city = DB::query('
        SELECT * FROM `city` WHERE `idcountry` IN %li', $country_id_array);

 // массив из ключей id городов (что бы вытащить улицы)
 $city_id = Transform::groupMassBykey($city,'id');

 // массив из ключей id улиц
 $city_id_array = array_column($city, 'id');

 //объединить страны и города
 foreach ($city_id as $key => $value) {
            $country_id[$value['idcountry']]['citys_array'][$key] = $value;
        }

 //все улицы к списку стран и городов
 $street= DB::query('
            SELECT `street`.*, `city`.`idcountry` 
            FROM `street` 
            LEFT JOIN `city` ON `city`.`id` = `streеt`.`idcity`
            WHERE `idcity` IN %li', $city_id_array
        );
        
  //объединить улицы и страны + города
  foreach ($street as $value) {
      $country_id[$value['idcountry']]['city_array'][$value['idcity']]['street'][] = $value;
        }

 result $country_id;
```

Comment: Укажите ТОЧНУЮ версию MySQL. Выложите тестовые данные в виде CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO и покажите требуемый результат для этих данных. В принципе - элементарно решается прямо на MySQL.

Comment: На MySQL это не возможно решить. На сегодня с сделал так: вытащил 3 отдельных массива данных и двумя циклами загнал один в другой. Но выглядит не очень красиво, я думал есть более проверенные и масштабируемые решения.

Comment: *На MySQL это не возможно решить.* Сказки.

Comment: Добавил в основное сообщение код своего текущего решения.

Comment: @Akina *Сказки*. Понты.

Comment: @Ипатьев Ну товарищ желает делать на стороне PHP. Возможно, потому что не сильно продвинут в SQL. Его право... А генерация многоуровневого JSON в MySQL - дело нехитрое, только что аккуратности требует.

Comment: @Akina ну вот это и есть понты :) понятно что безапелляционность автора с его "невозможно" его не красит, но "Сказки" вместо объяснения или хотя бы намёка - это понты :) Я вот тоже плаваю в джейсоне, хотя нагуглил ответ на большом сайте, да. И честно говоря я бы все равно делал в РНР

Comment: @МенеджерТипографии а почему бы не сделать всё одним запросом?

Comment: @Ипатьев *"Сказки" вместо объяснения или хотя бы намёка - это понты* Нет. Это констатация факта, что всё, что можно извлечь из данных вручную, можно извлечь и запросом. *вместо объяснения или хотя бы намёка* Ну охренеть... ты глянь мой первый коммент. Первые два предложения - за намёк не сойдёт, не?

Comment: @Akina туше! согласен, спорить с утверждением из первого коммента было со стороны автора неразумно.

Comment: Как вам решение использовать микро библиотеку rest api https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api ?